# Qt Creator debugger layout

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to alter the layout of the tool-bar icons?

The 'Continue' icon is right next to the 'Stop Debugger' icon, which is a really bad design and I've lost count of the number of times I meant to click continue but have accidentally clicked on the 'Stop Debugger' icon.

Comment: I prefer using the shortcuts, but can't tell you how to change the UI of the creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible to rearrange the buttons in the current build.

You have two options:

- Build Qt-Creator (or at least the "Debugger Plugin") from Source, and change the UI to your liking.
- Open a feature request on https://bugreports.qt.io/ and convince enough people to vote it up.

Comment: Agreed. It's a trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the keyboard short cuts. If you can't use a keyboard, consider using the fat "Run" button on the left bar which becomes a Continue button when stopped. This is ~300 pixels away from anything that could Stop debugging.